# What is the typical value of magnetic dipole of a magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

In the long range, a magnet can be approximated by a dipole. It produces a magnetic field $\vec B$:

$$\vec B = \frac{\mu}{4\pi}\left[\frac{3\vec r (\vec m · \vec r)}{r^5}-\frac{\vec m}{r^3}\right]$$

What is the typical value of a fridge magnet? Or some object that we can find at home.

Comment: Source: https://sciencing.com/strong-standard-magnet-685

Comment: According to the National High Magnetic Field Laboratory of Florida State University, a fridge magnet is about 0.001 tesla. To put that in perspective, the Earth's magnetic field is about 0.00005 tesla and an average MRI magnet measures 1.5 tesla.

Comment: @Sancol. That link is invalid.

Comment: Am I correct that you’re asking about the magnitude of $\vec m$, not the magnitude of $\vec B$?

Comment: https://sciencing.com/strong-standard-magnet-6853786.html is source link

Comment: Your formula is missing a [factor of 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole#External_magnetic_field_produced_by_a_magnetic_dipole_moment) in the first term.

Answer (score 0):

$10 \;\text{mT}$ was the value given by FSU's High Magnetic Field lab, though it depends on the size of the magnet and its composition.

Source:
https://nationalmaglab.org/about-the-maglab/around-the-lab/maglab-dictionary/tesla/

Comment: I think the OP is asking about the dipole moment $\vec m$.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm not sure where Sancol's value is since the link is not working.

I got my value from this webpage on the actual FSU maglab site: https://nationalmaglab.org/about-the-maglab/around-the-lab/maglab-dictionary/tesla/

Then using some simple  unit conversions:
100 Gauss = 0.01 Tesla = 10 milliTesla.

I got my result shown in the answer.

Comment: This link, https://sciencing.com/strong-standard-magnet-6853786.html, seems to be a working version on what Sancol has posted.